# HTTP POST not always executing in AWS Lambda in async/await handler

Tags: node.js, aws-lambda, async-await

Currently developing a NodeJS 18.x AWS Lambda function that must:

1. Download a file from location A to upload it to location B (easy)
2. POST a webhook in case of success/failure (not easy)

The POST webhook (see code below) is **not executed in AWS Lambda when the function is running for long time** (but still less than the 15m allowed in AWS Lambda) - probably that the AWS Lambda terminates without waiting all the code to be executed.

I tried to **promisify** the webhook HTTP request to **thenify** explicitly the `resolve()`, but without success.

Am I missing something?

```js
exports.handler = async (event) => {
    const downloadUrl = new URL(event.downloadUrl);
    const webhookUrl = new URL(event.webhookUrl);
    const uploadUrl = new URL(event.uploadUrl);
    const http = require("https");
    const request = (options = {}) => {
        options = Object.assign(options);
        return http.request(options);
    };

    // Webhook handler
    function webhookRequest(params, postData) {
        return new Promise(function(resolve, reject) {
            var req = http.request(params, function(res) {
                if (res.statusCode < 200 || res.statusCode >= 300) {
                    return reject(new Error('statusCode=' + res.statusCode));
                }
                var body = [];
                res.on('data', function(chunk) {
                    body.push(chunk);
                });
                res.on('end', function() {
                    try {
                        body = JSON.parse(Buffer.concat(body).toString());
                    } catch (e) {
                        reject(e);
                    }
                    resolve(body);
                });
            });
            req.on('error', function(err) {
                reject(err);
            });
            if (postData) {
                req.write(JSON.stringify(postData));
            }
            req.end();
        });
    }
    // Webhook http.request options
    let webhookOptions = {
        hostname: webhookUrl.hostname,
        path: webhookUrl.pathname,
        port: 443,
        method: "POST",
        headers: {
            'Content-Type': 'application/json',
        },
    };
    // Webhook POST data
    let postData = {
        'fileUrl': uploadUrl.protocol + "//" + uploadUrl.hostname + uploadUrl.pathname,
    };
    // Main work
    await new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
        let download = request({
            hostname: downloadUrl.hostname,
            path: downloadUrl.pathname + downloadUrl.search,
            port: 443
        });
        // Start downloading from location A and upload to location B
        download.on("response", (res) => {
            console.log("Response from download", res.headers);
            let upload = request({
                hostname: uploadUrl.hostname,
                path: uploadUrl.pathname + uploadUrl.search,
                port: 443,
                method: "PUT",
                headers: {
                    'Content-Length': res.headers['content-length']
                }
            });
            upload.on("response", (resUpload) => {
                let chunks = [];
                resUpload.on("data", (chunk) => {
                    chunks.push(chunk);
                });
                resUpload.on("end", () => {
                    console.log("StatusCode = " + resUpload.statusCode)
                    if (resUpload.statusMessage == "OK" || resUpload.statusCode == 200) {
                        postData.message = "TRANSFER_SUCCESS";
                        postData.timeStamp = new Date();
                        webhookRequest(webhookOptions, postData).then( // <-- Not executed
                            resolve({
                                statusCode: resUpload.statusCode
                            })
                        );
                    } else {
                        console.error(resUpload.statusMessage);
                        postData.message = "UPLOADING_ERROR : " + resUpload.statusMessage;
                        postData.timeStamp = new Date();
                        webhookRequest(webhookOptions, postData).then(  // <-- Not executed
                            reject({
                                statusCode: resUpload.statusCode
                            })
                        );
                    }
                });
            });
            upload.on("error", (err) => {
                console.error(JSON.stringify(err));
                postData.message = "UPLOADING_ERROR : " + JSON.stringify(err);
                postData.timeStamp = new Date();
                webhookRequest(webhookOptions, postData).then(  // <-- Not executed
                    reject({
                        statusCode: 500
                    })
                );
            });
            res.pipe(upload);
        });
        download.on("error", (err) => {
            console.error(JSON.stringify(err));
            postData.message = "DOWNLOADING_ERROR : " + JSON.stringify(err);
            postData.timeStamp = new Date();
            webhookRequest(webhookOptions, postData).then(  // <-- Not executed
                reject({
                    statusCode: 500
                })
            );
        });
        download.end();
    });
};
```